# What port is this? Lenovo y50-70

Tags: lenovo-laptop

Please help me find out, I'm very curious about what this port could be and I have literally no clue to what it might be. If you know or have any idea please let me know!

[image]

Answer (score 41):

It looks like [Kensington lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kensington_Security_Slot) - not really a port, just a hole used to secure the device to some immovable object.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kensington_Security_Slot  "A Kensington Security Slot (also called a K-Slot or Kensington lock) is part of an anti-theft system designed and patented by Kryptonite in 1999-2000, assigned to Schlage in 2002, and since 2005 owned and marketed by Kensington Computer Products Group, a division of ACCO Brands."

Answer (score 6):

Left: USB port (but I'm sure your question isn't targeted here!)

Right: Not a port, it's a Kensington lock slot (that's the reason for the chain pictogram beside it)